# TCP/IP Socket Broadcasting

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to know if TCP/IP can broadcast... I created a sample code below and I'm wondering if what I have is wrong, because it seem client side never receive anything...

```
    public void broadcast(string data)
{
    byte[] dataByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    foreach(Socket so in ClientList)
    {
        so.Send(dataByte);
    }
}
```

It will be great if someone point out why my client side never receive anything.

Comment: What is in `ClientList`? What does `Send()` return?

Comment: `Send()` is a function of a socket that usually send the `byte[]` overto socket, and `ClientList` is a `List<Socket>` that contain all socket that connected to server

Comment: Let me try again: how do you initialize your listening socket? Do your clients successfully connect? Are any clients connected at the moment of calling, is `ClientList` filled? And `Send()` returns an `int` indicating how many bytes were sent. Does your entire byte array get sent? How do you read on your clients, how do you determine that _"client side never receive anything"_?

Comment: yes, my client connect succesfully, and the `ClientList` filled, and `Send()` returned the correct bytes, also I can determine that "my client never receive anything" is that client will print out the message directly for anything that its receive, but yet my client never print anything.

Comment: Well from your explanation, everything should work. It doesn't. Please show _how_ you initialize your listening socket, and show the code your clients use to connect, read and print the data.

Comment: I think I know the answer on my own, after re reading my code, I forgot to `BeginReceive`. sorry for wasting your time here. and Thank you for your concern @CodeCaster.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely my own problem that the client never receive anything because I never call `BeginReceive` code...